# Clip-path doesn't scale properly

Tags: html, css

When I shrink my browser I end up with the image below:

[image]

For some reason when I scale my browser from top to bottom the image scales perfectly, but from left to right or right to left (testing the responsiveness of the page) the image doesn't scale at all.

HTML

```
 <section>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row" id="bio">
            <div >
                <img src="/img.png" id="bio-image" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="ml-5 mr-5">
                <h2>Fueled by Innovation ...</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo similique illum obcaecati impedit voluptas
                        quasi, labore libero corrupti aliquam? Pariatur dolorem quae, error, officia, veritatis alias blanditiis
                        neque explicabo quos ad inventore distinctio odit necessitatibus odio iure repellendus. Doloremque
                        doloribus odio in illo officiis maxime magni molestiae delectus assumenda recusandae!</p>
             </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
    #bio-image {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    height: 40vh;
    opacity: 0.5; 
}

    #bio {
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

I've been messing around with it a lot but haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: change `height: auto` instead of `height: 40vh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the height to "auto" and add width. Check below for correct CSS

```
#bio-image {
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
      height: auto;
      opacity: 0.5; 
      max-width: 50vw;
  }
```

Check here https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/abzzqBe

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked really well. The max-width value is the game changer here!

Answer (score 0):

```css
   #bio-image {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.5; 
}

    #bio {
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
   
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row" id="bio">
            <div >
                <img src="http://localhost:80/egs-api/XSCAssets/user/157381030912898154625dce70854c0ba.jpg" id="bio-image" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="ml-5 mr-5">
                <h2>Fueled by Innovation ...</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo similique illum obcaecati impedit voluptas
                        quasi, labore libero corrupti aliquam? Pariatur dolorem quae, error, officia, veritatis alias blanditiis
                        neque explicabo quos ad inventore distinctio odit necessitatibus odio iure repellendus. Doloremque
                        doloribus odio in illo officiis maxime magni molestiae delectus assumenda recusandae!</p>
             </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The height auto paired with max-width worked.